# Why do some C/C++ headers have "sys/" in front of them?

Tags: c++, c, header

Some C/C++ headers like `<sys/ioctl.h>` have a `sys/` prefix in front of them.

(There are also some with a `net/` prefix.)

Why is this?

Comment: Because they're in the sub-directory 'sys' of wherever the include files are.

Comment: These headers aren't defined by the C(++) standards - these are OS-specific.

Comment: Suppose i write a `source.c` file inside a folder named test. If iput all headers defined by me inside inner folder `hd`, for using header i must write their addresses something like: `#include <hd/myheader.h>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Practically, this shows those file are under a sub-folder named "sys" in  one of the standard list of system directories (e.g compiler default search path, or folder given as a parameter during the build).

The reason they are in a sub-folder is to indicate they are not a part of the c or c++ standard libraries, but rather a specific extension, usually provided by the operating system you are working in.

Note that this is only a matter of conventions, and not part of the specified behavior by C or C++. Usually to really understand those kind of header you will look at further documentation provided by the operating system you are working under.

Comment: Well, *sys/*, *net/* etc, and headers under them is defined by POSIX standard (I believe, did not verify), so it's not just a convention any more than C standard headers are a convention.